# Sorting data by Job number and subtracting Dates in R studio

Tags: r

I have this data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQhFi.png)

and i am trying to sort by job number and get the beginning date minus the end date to see hw many days or months the job took. i get the answer in the picture which is not right. any idea?

```
X2019Data$dateDiff<-ave(as.numeric(X2019Data$date), X2019Data$JOBNUMBER_I, FUN=function(x) c(abs(diff(x)),0))
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult to do that the way your data is. I would suggest starting by filling in the missing data, grouping by job number, then you could do something like max(date)  - min(date).

Comment: What do the NA rows between two JOBNUMBER_T stand for? Do they pertain to the previous non-NA jobnumber? I.e., in your data, are there 4 new info lines for the job 015B122, which therefore started on 2008-12-31 and ended on 2009-05-31?

Comment: there are NA's in the job numbers because of the dates. there isn't just a start date and an end end date in the data. there are dates, when things were done on the same job hence the gaps and NA's. Thank you!